# How to tokenize both white-spaced and quoted string, handling escaping?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to tokenize a string, such that tokens are either:

1. inside double quotes
2. white-space separated

quoted strings must deal with escaping: `this: "is included in \"single token\""` should become either this:

```
[this:] [is included in "single token"]
```

or this:

```
[this:] [is included in \"single token\"]
```

(token is `@"[^\s]"`, not `@"\w"`)

I've seen many solution to partial problems:

- find all quoted strings - but that leaves all unquoted tokens out
- find all unquoted tokens - that leave out quoted strings

unfortunately I couldn't find a way to fuse these two problems' solutions together...

---

this is what I have thus far:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var inputs = new List<string>
        {
            @"bef\`ore`xy z`after",
            @"start `with simple` expression: `i am xprsion` and this is empty: `` ...",
            @"now       `with       some    tabs`       expression",
            @"nothing \but\ escapers\\\",
            @"some  #@   other   kind$    of    whildcards...",
            @"and now `with \`allegedly\` escape` char",
            @"tight`  or even   `connected",
        }.Select(s => s.Replace('`', '"'));

    var sections = new[]
        {
            @"(?<i>[^\s]+)",
            @"((?<!\\)`(?<i>.*?)(?<!\\)`)", // quoted
        };

    var pattern = string.Join("|", sections).Replace("`","\"");

    foreach (var i in inputs)
    {
        Regex.Matches(i, pattern)
             .Cast<Match>()
             .Select(m => m.Groups["i"].Value)
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(s => Console.Write("[{0}]", s));

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

but the combination of both the quoted-pattern and the white-space-separation-pattern ruins it all...

Comment: Regular expressions are a very bad way to tokenize like this. They can tokenize some basic text well.. but when you start throwing character escapes and nested tokens into the mix they are useless.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I generally agree, but believe that this is a case simple enough for RegEx, as Anirudh showed below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match using this regex

```
(?<=[^\\]|^)".*?(?<=[^\\])"|(\\"|[\w])+
```

Don;t forget to escape `"` with `""` and using a verbatim string `@`

```
 Regex.Matches(input,yourRegex)
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(x=>x.Value)
      .ToList();
```

[Demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=b2ac4c4f-bde4-475b-9639-cae8c6f9ec18){you can't change the input here,open a new instance of that site}

Comment: with just one change (`[\w]` -> `[^\s"]`) - it works. Thanks!